# In Julia: Find the mean of an array with missing values

Tags: julia, missing-data

The Statistics package `mean` function returns `missing` if any elements of an `array` are missing.

```
julia> using Statistics
julia> mean([1 2 3 4 5] )
3.0
julia> mean([1 2 missing 4 5] )  # Note missing value
missing
```

How do I get the mean of the non-missing values?

Comment: [_First-Class Statistical Missing Values Support in Julia_...](https://julialang.org/blog/2018/06/missing) provides a nice overview, a survey, and some depth of dealing with missing values in statistical computing. Of note, "... missing values should never be silently ignored ... This behavior is known to have caused incorrect results in published scientific work."

Comment: Wow!  I have just had time to do a quick scan of your link, but it looks very useful.  Thanks much.

Comment: See also https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/missing/#Skipping-Missing-Values-1

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat Thanks for adding that documentation link..

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat I added your link to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `skipmissing` function will send only the non-missing elements to the `mean` function:

```
julia> using Statistics
julia> mean([1 2 3 4 5] )
3.0https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/missing/#Skipping-Missing-Values-1
julia> mean([1 2 missing 4 5] )  # Note missing value
missing
# Here is the answer:
julia> mean(skipmissing([1 2 missing 4 missing] ))
2.3333333333333335
```

As pointed out by @Milan Bouchet-Valat in a comment to the question, the docs on `missing` are [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/missing/#Skipping-Missing-Values-1).  They are a good quick, first read on Julia's handling of missing values.